# How we can save a html page after drag and drop changes

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

I am working on html DnD . I see a lot of tutorials on internet and got a example od DnD  http://jsbin.com/axegem/1 . Now after reordering objects of these page I want to save it , But I don't know how I can do that please any one can help .

Thanks !!

Comment: you just need to save the style of the "div position: relative; left: 407px; top: 197px;"

Comment: @HudsonPH : thanks sir for reply but I don't know how I can save it there have any link or example any tutorial for that . please give some more details .

Comment: where do you want save?

Comment: @HudsonPH : I have a web UI , I want make it drag-able or drop-able every  element , SO after save it will be reloaded with new changes , that I want . We can save it anywhere but requirement is only reload latest changes .

Comment: try this:  jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/v685v9t6

Comment: @HudsonPH : that actually thing which I want but when I copy it and save it in a html file load from browser that is not working . :(

Comment: you need edit the id e.e do you know js?

Comment: @HudsonPH : Sir, I have basic knowledge of js . There have not e.e . please give little more info .

Comment: show me the wha you did after i sent this code

Comment: @HudsonPH :  please see following link : https://codeshare.io/Nw4FO

Comment: you need insert the references jquery.js and jquery-ui.js

Comment: @HudsonPH : Thank you sir , you answering my basic questions every time , thank you very much !! last question can we do that for multiple elements of html I mean multiple divs .

Comment: @HudsonPH : please give some idea how I can implement it for multiple html elements .

Comment: @HudsonPH : Please sir give little more help , Can we save these positions in a file or read these and populate html .

Comment: you can save in json file

Comment: @HudsonPH : Can you give me any example for reference . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I made a update: https://jsfiddle.net/f7fq7n94/

```
$("#draggable4").draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        positions[this.id] = ui.position
        localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
    }
});
$("#draggable5").draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        positions[this.id] = ui.position
        localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for give that support and help . That is very good example . Thank you !!  :)

Comment: I have one question after see this . why we can not use single id and also only one js function because every function is same ?

Comment: yes you can do thiis, just catch the current div and set the event

Comment: One another thing when I replace div with input tag that is not working any reason for that .

Comment: if your İnput id="draggable5" so in jquery need to be $("#draggable5")

Comment: Sir I post updated code in answer , there have two input tags that is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<h1>Avis DnD </h1>

<div id="containment-wrapper">
    <input id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">


    <input id="draggable4" class="draggable ui-widget-content">

  </div>
<script>
var sPositions = localStorage.positions || "{}",
    positions = JSON.parse(sPositions);
$.each(positions, function (id, pos) {
    $("#" + id).css(pos)
})
$("#draggable3").draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        positions[this.id] = ui.position
        localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
    }
});
$("#draggable4").draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        positions[this.id] = ui.position
        localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
    }
});
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: did you insert the jquery and jquery ui in the head of your page?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: yes, that is totally same like working code which is for div tag , I change only div with input tag .

Comment: If I want insert positions of div in file and after reloading page and  pop html as per as file values. Then what I can do for that .

Comment: @HudsonPH : please help give any example of save values of positions in server side .